# Create table for specific log format in Athena

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-athena

Need help creating a schema for the below log format. I'm using Athena in order to query a bunch of logs that have this format but I'm having an issue creating the table for this specific log format. I'v tried a couple different attempts and have failed. Below is also the latest create table statement attempt, but also keeps failing.

```
CREATE TABLE "fastly_logs" (
  "some_num" int,
  "timestamp1" timestamp,
  "cache_value" string,
  "some_fastly" string,  
  "log_info" struct <
                request_ipv4: string,    
                request_https: int,
                request: string,
                request_host: string,
                request_uri: string,
                http_code: int,
                response: int,
                req_header_size: int,
                req_body_size: int,
                resp_header_size: int,
                resp_body_size: int,
                content_type: string,
                pop: string,
                device_type: string,
                referrer: string,
                request_user_agent: string,
                info_state: string,
                hits: int,
                tls_version: string,
                >
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1',
  'input.regex' = '^\D(\d{3})\D (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T.*Z) (cache-\D+{3}+\d{4,10}) (Prod-fastly\D+\d{6}\D) {(.*)}'
)
LOCATION 's3://prod-fastly/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='true')
```

Log format:

```
<134>2020-02-10T16:04:22Z cache-dca17767 Prod-fastly[476113]: {"timestamp":"Mon, 10 Feb 2020 16:04:22 GMT", "request_ipv4":"111.111.111.111", "request_https":"true", "tls_version":"TLSv1.2", "request":"POST", "request_host":"test.example.com", "vp_stem":"www", "request_uri":"/this/ajax-test", "http_code":200, "response":"OK", "req_header_size":1215, "req_body_size":54, "resp_header_size":916, "resp_body_size":16, "content_type":"application/json", "pop":"DCA", "device_type":"", "referrer":"https://test.example.copm/some/path", "request_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36", "info_state":"PASS", "hits":0 }
```

Comment: Did you try defining the log_info as a string and using the parse_json on the query time? It can give more flexibility to handle errors in the format.

Comment: No, could you show me an example ?

Comment: @Guy the full line isn't JSON, so that wouldn't work

Comment: Have you tried validating your regex pattern over multiple examples lines rather than just this one?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using \D if you know what characters are possible. To start, there's no space before the date, so that immediately doesn't match. Should be `<(\d+)>`

`^\D(\d{3})\D`

Your date looks fine, but I don't know what format `timestamp` expects

`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T.*Z)`

The cache looks fine, but the values seem to be hexadecimal, so you should use `cache-[0-9a-fA-F]{1,13}`, for example

`(cache-\D+{3}+\d{4,10})`

Again, don't use the \D. It'd be better to go for `Prod-fastly\[\d+\]`

`(Prod-fastly\D+\d{6}\D)`

The rest is all a JSON object, yes, but you should not attempt to parse it, so it's type must be a string. And just `(.*)$` would do; don't put curly brackets

`{(.*)}`

And I'd suggest allowing for more than one space between fields

In all

`^<(\d+)>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T.*Z)\s+(cache-[0-9a-fA-F]{1,13})\s+(Prod-fastly\[\d+\])\s+(.*)$`

You need to make this raw plaintext table, then you can make another table with the struct and parse the json object there during an insert/select statement

```
CREATE TABLE "fastly_logs" (
  "some_num" int,
  "timestamp1" timestamp,
  "cache_value" string,
  "some_fastly" string,  
  "remainder" string)
```

Then try something like

`SELECT json extract(remainder, "$.request_host") FROM fastly_logs;`

Comment: I've been gauging my eyes out here. If I understand you correctly, I would first create a table plaintext for this data, then another "tmp" table that can read from that table, to which will be able to query the json ? If so, could you help me building out the create tables for these ?

Comment: I would call your plaintext table as "raw_logs" and the other not "tmp", but just "logs". Forget the JSON for a minute. Can you query the logs with above regex? Wait until you can, then see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html